# Many to One in hibernate, get column type

Tags: java, hibernate, properties

In Hibernate when I got simple Pojo, for example User:

```
private class User{
   private String name;
}
```

When I want to get property of the "name", a simply use:

```
sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(User.class).getPropertyType("name")
```

But when I add a class Grou to my User:

```
private class User{
   private String name;
   private Group group;
}
```

My previous code :

```
  sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(User.class).getPropertyType("group.name")
```

doesn't work. 
Any way to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

Split your query `group.name` into the corresponding parts `group` and `name`.

```
Class<?> currentClass = User.class;
for(String field: "group.name".split("\\Q.\\E")) {
    currentClass = sessionFactory.getClassMetadata(currentClass).getPropertyType(field);
}
```

Comment: sorry, but I cannot understand. what split("\\Q.\\E") does ?

Comment: [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)) Split() splits a string into several parts around the symbol that is matched (in this case, the `.`). The `.` is surrounded by `\Q` and `\E` which makes it being interpreted literally. Without this, the `.` is a special symbol in regular expressions meaning 'any character'. In java, `\Q` becomes `\\Q`, because `\Q` is interpreted as 'special symbol `Q`'. This is similar to `\t` being interpreted as 'TAB SYMBOL'.

Answer (score 0):

for `group.name` to work , you have to specify the mapping for Group class also.
If you have already specified a mapping and still its not working then please share the mapping file here.
Issue might be in the mapping only.